# Getting tableView rowHeight in custom cell (programmatically)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I'm having a really hard time trying to communicate between my custom cell (TicketCell.swift) and my table view controller (MarketTableViewController.swift). So I have about 40 cells being imported into my table and I want to place a button on the right side of each cell

Here is my code for my button inside TicketCell:

```
lazy var purchaseButton : UIButton = {
  let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.bounds.width - 30, y: self.bounds.height/2, width: 64, height: 24))
  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(purchaseButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
  button.layer.cornerRadius = 4
  button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
  button.layer.borderWidth = 1
  button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
  return button
}()
```

but as you can see here, it doesn't center it the way I want it to:
[image]
[image]

I want it to always be on the right side no matter what orientation the phone is in and also centered vertically in the cell.

In MarketTableViewControleler I have set the height of each cell using this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

And I cannot seem to access this height variable from my custom cell, Ive tried all the following:

```
contentView.frame.height
contentView.bounds.height
self.bounds.height
Constants.ViewControllers.marketTableViewController.tableView.frame.height
Constants.ViewController.marketTableViewController.tableView.rowHeight
```

I've even tried using a delegate to pass the tableView to the custom cell, but it just gives me the same information as I get from my Constants class. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely solve it using constraints. Setting `.right` constraint with respect to the superview and `.left` constraint with respect to the content you want to display on the left side should work. To center the button you could use `.centerY` constraint equal to superview.

But setting constraints everywhere, for all your subviews might become a little difficult to manage later on, specially when you start handling orientation changes etc. I would suggest looking into `UIStackView` as well. You can easily use a horizontal stackview to implement this type of custom view. You can set the `distribution` as per your requirement and setting `alignment` to `.center` will vertically center the button in your cell.

You can check out [this](https://pusher.com/tutorials/auto-layout-swift-part-5) article. It looks similar to what you might be trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to constraint your sub-views to maintain the layout when orientation changes. Here's is how:

```swift
class TicketCell: UITableViewCell {
    lazy var purchaseButton : UIButton = {
      let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.bounds.width - 30, y: self.bounds.height/2, width: 64, height: 24))
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(purchaseButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
      button.layer.cornerRadius = 4
      button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
      button.layer.borderWidth = 1
      button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
      return button
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        addSubview(purchaseButton)

        purchaseButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            purchaseButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 16),
            purchaseButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16)])
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Note: Here I'm constraining the `purchaseButton` to the `TicketCell` so that it has a padding of 16 from the top and right corners, you can change it to any desired value you like.

Comment: Thanks. That definitely fixed a lot of the problems with the orientation. I'm still having a problem accessing the height component of each row. I set that in my TableViewController, but I can't find a single variable to access that height. With the way I have it now, the buttons are a little high in each row.